# Travis CI running on Docker Image - Switch to last comited branch

Tags: git, docker, branch, travis-ci

I'm working on an operating systems, and I want to use **Travis CI** for continuous integration.
Basically, my OS can perform a bunch of kernel tests on boot, and I want them to be run at every push.

However, setup environment is a bit complex, and so I'm using a **Docker Image** that I want my application to be run on the Docker Image, exactly like Tavis CI's example is doing: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/

As you can see in the Dockefile of the example: https://github.com/travis-ci/docker-sinatra/blob/master/Dockerfile , repo is clonned inside the Image, and soin Travis CI's configuration file (https://github.com/travis-ci/docker-sinatra/blob/master/.travis.yml), they just have to run "make".

This is easy because this project is a single branch project, but me I want the tests to be operated to the lastest comitted branch (The one which triggered Travis's build).

Which solution do you think I can use for this? Using environment variables on Travis CI that I the pass to Docker image and then checkout the branch passed as parameter? There is not more "classy options"?

I think both my Docker file and .travis.yml files are not necessary as there are WIP. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the branch that was last committed to you can use a shell script like this:

```
git branch --sort=-committerdate | awk -F " " /*/'{print $2}'
```

The `awk` command is just cleaning up the output from the `branch` command so only the branch name is returned.

You can use the result of the above with `git checkout` to switch to the last updated branch before your `make` command.

Comment: @Turbolay thanks. I updated my command above a bit, as I was able to have `awk` do the work that `grep` was doing (thus it's a bit shorter)